# GraphQL endCursor and React State

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a pagination on my react fe. I'm calling my data on page load and setting the endCursor for the pagination into a react hook variable.

However when I click 'load more' button on my page it goes and fetches new data and should upset the endCursor with the new value retrieved... but it only does this once and then stops working. I'm sure I'm doing something silly but I can't figure out what.

Here's the code..

```
const LatestDrops = () => {

    const [newArrivals, setNewArrivals] = useState([])
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState('')

    // Run on page load
    useEffect(() => {
        listNewArrivals()
    },[])

    // Fetch new arrivals
    const listNewArrivals = () => {
        getNewArrivals()
            .then(data => {
                if (data.error){
                    console.log('Error fetching new arrivals', data.error)
                } else {
                    setNewArrivals(data.edges)
                    setOffset(data.pageInfo.endCursor)
                }
            })
            .catch(e => console.log('Failed to fetch', e))
    }

    // Fetch more arrivals on click
    const handleLoadMore = (e) => {
        console.log('Fetching more with offset: ', offset)
        getMarketPlaceListings(offset)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.error){
                    console.log('Error fetching marketplace listings', data.error)
                } else {
                    setNewArrivals(data.edges)
                    console.log('Page offset from server is: ', data.pageInfo.endCursor)
                    setOffset(data.pageInfo.endCursor)
                }
            })
    }

    return(
        <section>
            Cursor: {JSON.stringify(offset)}
            <button onClick={e => handleLoadMore()}>
                View all
            </button>
        </section>
    )
}

export default LatestDrops
```

I've also tried throwing in the old state when updating it as suggested by another post ie:

```
setOffset(offset => data.pageInfo.endCursor)
```